# Magento what is system configuration page route?

Tags: magento, routes

Hi my question for today is:

What route is for system->configuration->advanced->system page ?

or have to get the url by routing ? i tried this:

```
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getUrl('*/system')
```

but it isnt working. is `'*/system'` route correct for that path ? or what is the correct router for that path ?

Comment: Vardius, is it  working??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getUrl('*/system_config/*/*');
```

this work

```
$shipment_url = Mage::helper('adminhtml')
    ->getUrl(
      'adminhtml/sales_order_shipment/view',
      array('shipment_id' => $shipment_id));
$url = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getUrl('*/system/e');
```

Comment: yes it it is i used more specific path for route url `getUrl('*/system_config/edit/section/system/')`
and it is the form page i wanted